# Angular-cli set host to non- .com domain when serving for development

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

When running an ng serve on my angular cli build, I'm trying to set the host to a .ca domain so that I can resolve some CORS and cookie issues during development. When trying it with a .com domain it works no problem:

Works with .com domain:

```
ng serve --host localhost.mydomain.com
```

But when I try with a .ca, doesn't work:

```
ng serve --host localhost.mydomain.ca
```

I get the error:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost.mydomain.ca
```

Is there anything I can do to make the .ca part work?

Thanks

Edit: I'm on mac OSX El Capitan

Comment: Windows or iOS?

Comment: @joh04667 mac OS

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to edit your local `hosts` file to be able to recognize that domain. Open `/etc/hosts` and add the following:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost.mydomain.ca
```

...but replace with your local ip.

Comment: dump question, but where is the host file? or the folder /etc?

Comment: Assuming you're on OSX/Linux, it's in your root directory, so you can't get there naturally with Finder. Either shift + command + G from Finder and manually go to `/etc/hosts` or open Terminal and run `open /etc/hosts`. Windows is just in a different location, C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts